# SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 65), address = x.x.x.x, port = 80

Tags: dart

I have a problem of my app.
When I request the server use dio, I will get this error:

> `Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 65), address = 192.168.10.241, port = 80`

And on some phone there is no error but on some phone it will show these errors.
I cannot figure it out.
Please answer for that if you know.

`'flutter doctor -v'` is natural

Comment: did you find what the issue was? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, I fixed by uninstalling the antivírus on my iPad. Reference: [Chathuranga Jayawardhana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67896069/4508758)

If not works, check if the App is pointing to the **correct iPv4 and port** of the server on your local network

Setting [NSAllowsArbitraryLoads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32331282/4508758) to true may help for local tests as well (not recommended in production)